# Spring boot / MongoDB : expecting to have different URL for GET and DELETE

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I started to learn spring boot 2 days ago, I've read a lots of articles but unfortunately it does not work as expected (I'm a Ruby on Rails developper, it's a bit difficult for me to learn Java ;) )

I want to create a "simple" REST application in order to create, get and delete a Tag class and I use mongoDB.

My understanding is that I have to create a TagRepository file with this content:

```
package com.petstore.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.petstore.models.Tag;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "tags", path="tags")
public interface TagRepository extends MongoRepository<Tag, String> {

}
```

I expect the ability to manage the following URLs:

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/tags
GET: http://localhost:8080/tag/:id
DELETE: http://localhost:8080/tag/:id
```

Unfortunately I can only use

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/tags
GET: http://localhost:8080/tags/:id
DELETE: http://localhost:8080/tags/:id
```

If I try the delete URL (/tag/:id) I have this error message 
*Request method 'DELETE' not supported*

but if I use the delete URL (/tags/:id) it works fine.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sharing my sample code which worked by renaming to tag

My main class

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class SpringBootDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Model Class

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Tag
{
    @Id
    String id;
    String tag;

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTag()
    {
        return tag;
    }
    public void setTag(String tag)
    {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

and finally our repository class

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "tags", path="tag")
public interface TagRepository extends MongoRepository<Tag, String>
{
    @RestResource(path = "tags")
    Page<Tag> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    void delete(String tag);
}
```

with sample above code you can start spring boot code and when you hit http://localhost:8080/tag you can see all tags and similarly you can retrieve single tag by hitting url http://localhost:8080/tag/:id and delete by http://localhost:8080/tag/:id

below is my pom which i have used to demonstrate the above code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MongoDB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

With this code we can obtained your desired url paths

Answer (score 0):

You will need to autowire in your mongoTemplate into Spring boot. There are quite a few threads on this topic, you can find how to configure this on SO so you will need to search for the answer on here:

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Then you will need to create your method and query your mongodb using the mongotemplate:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/mymethod_fetch", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List myMethod(@RequestParam String name) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").is(name));
        query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id"));
        query.limit(10);
        List<Object> obj = mongoTemplate.find(query, Object.class);
        return obj;
    }
```

This is the one for delete:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/mymethod_item_delete", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void myMethod(@RequestParam String name) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").is(name));
        mongoTemplate.remove(query, Object.class);
    }
```

Point your browser to the api endpoints, which is normally http://127.0.0.1:8080/mymethod_fetch and you will see the results in your browser.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it soon.

I found a workaround but it's very hugly. I overwrite the methods in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I will try it soon.

I found a workaround but it's very hugly. I overwrite the methods in the controller. Here an example for PetController:

```
  @Autowired
      private PetRepository petRepository;

      @RequestMapping(value = "/pet/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      @ResponseBody
      public Pet findOneRemapped(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
          return petRepository.findOne(id); 
      }
```

Comment: Hi. Yes, you can use that method but usig the repository class to do your work means you cannot customise your searches sometimes, like sorts etc.